# rubygems.org, releasing a gem and extra stuff

Tags: rubygems, hyperlink

I can't believe I have to ask this question, but, the answer simply is not jumping out at me.  When looking at a gem hosted on rubygems.org, there are sometimes extra links to things like source code, documentation, wiki, bug tracker, etc.  I have downloaded several gems and haven't discovered the necessary steps to configure those types of links for my own gems.  I did find an API.

curl https://rubygems.org/api/v1/gems/rails.json

This will return some json about the gem and there are put, post methods for the api.  I would like to update attributes like: homepage_uri, wiki_uri, documentation_uri, mailing_list_uri, source_code_uri, bug_tracker_uri

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

These can be added by editing your gem after publishing the gem to RubyGems. The edit URL is `https://rubygems.org/gems/<gem_name>/edit`

Example:

[image: Gem page]

The other details are entered/updated in the Gemspec file.

Comment: I'd just like to point out, that starting with RubyGems 2.0, you can add these extra fields via a `metadata` attribute. For more info, check http://guides.rubygems.org/specification-reference/ .